# Online course to learn PHP similar to Rails for Zombies?

Tags: php, wordpress

I really enjoyed Rails for Zombies and the myriad of online courses teaching Rails.
This is the best way to learn for me: jump right in with a project and a reference book basically.

Is there a PHP course out there like that that you can recommend?

PS. I'm interested in making themes/plugins for Wordpress but I find that my knowledge of PHP itself is pretty weak, so it'd be neat to do some novice course.

Comment: I can't think of any off of the top of my head, but thanks for Rails for Zombies - I've been looking for a good online course to learn rails!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't actually used this site, but it appears to be similar to RfZ based on using video as the delivery media:

http://www.phpvideotutorials.com/free

As a note, some content is free and some is not.

Comment: That's pretty good, thanks man

Comment: Thanks...considering this is from over one year ago, I wouldn't be surprised.  That said, if you have an updated/better link to contribute, I would welcome your contribution and gladly credit you in an update to my answer.